# Custom password for kubernetes dashboard when using eks

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

Is it possible to configure a custom password for the Kubernetes dashboard when using **eks** without customizing "kube-apiserver"?
This URL mentions changes in "kube-apiserver"
https://techexpert.tips/kubernetes/kubernetes-dashboard-user-authentication/

Comment: Due to `EKS` being a `cloud-managed` solution I'd reckon that you won't have access to `kubeapi-server` to change those options. `EKS` have a dedicated [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html) for using `Dashboard`. I encourage you to check it out.

Comment: have you had a chance to look on the guide I gave you? Have you tried the solution posted by Harsh Manvar?

Answer (score 0):

In K8s, requests come as Authentication and Authorization (so the API server can determine if this user can perform the requested action). K8s dont have users, in the simple meaning of that word (Kubernetes users are just strings associated with a request through credentials). The credential strategy is a choice you make while you install the cluster (you can choose from x509, password files, Bearer tokens, etc.).

Without API K8s server automatically falls back to an anonymous user and there is no way to check if provided credentials are valid.

You can do something like :  **not tested**

- Create a new credential using OpenSSL

> export NEW_CREDENTIAL=USER:$(echo PASSWORD | openssl passwd -apr1
> -noverify -stdin)

- Append the previously created credentials to
  /opt/bitnami/kubernetes/auth.

> ```
> echo $NEW_CREDENTIAL | sudo tee -a /opt/kubernetes/auth
> ```

Replace the cluster basic-auth secret.

```
kubectl delete secret basic-auth -n kube-system

kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=/opt/kubernetes/auth -n kube-system
```